# Validation of form in another php script?

Tags: php, forms

I'd like to know if it is possible to manage error if in the form, action is set to another script.

ajoutDevis.php

```
<FORM name='devis' method='POST' action='ajoutDevisScript.php' id='form'>
<label for="client">Client</label>
<input type='text' id='client' name='client'>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $clientErr;?></span>
</FORM>
```

ajoutDevisScript.php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if(empty($_POST['client'])) {
            $clientErr = "ERROR";
        } else $client = $_POST['client'];
```

So, is it possible to display my error in the span if the input is empty ? Or there is no way doing it with an other script as action ?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are going to use session variables to display errors, remember to unlink/remove the session variable after displaying or else the error will keep on displaying.   try: unlink($_SESSION['error']);      ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if(empty($_POST['client'])) {
            $clientErr = "ERROR";
            $_SESSION['error] = $clentErr;
            header('location:ajoutDevis.php');

        } else $client = $_POST['client'];

In your ajoutDevis.php file


session_start();
$clientErr = ($_SESSION['error']!='')?$_SESSION['error']:'';
<FORM name='devis' method='POST' action='ajoutDevisScript.php' id='form'>
<label for="client">Client</label>
<input type='text' id='client' name='client'>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $clientErr;?></span>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

Add the form code as well on the ajoutDevisScript.php page at the bottom of page.

```
<?php if(!empty($clientErr)) { ?>
    <FORM name='devis' method='POST' action='ajoutDevisScript.php' id='form'>
    <label for="client">Client</label>
    <input type='text' id='client' name='client'>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $clientErr;?></span>
    </FORM>
<?php } ?>
```

This will check if there is any error in error variable it will display the form on same page with error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possibile with `$_SESSION` variables to store values during the session and `header()` function to redirect user from the second script back to the first.
Supposing both files are in the root directory, **ajoutDevis.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<FORM name='devis' method='POST' action='ajoutDevisScript.php' id='form'>
    <label for="client">Client</label>
    <input type='text' id='client' name='client'>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['clientErr'])) : ?>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['clientErr'] ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</FORM>
```

and **ajoutDevisScript.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST['client'])) {
        $_SESSION['clientErr'] = "ERROR";
        header('Location: ajoutDevis.php');
    } else {
        $client = $_POST['client'];
    }
}
?>
```

I would suggest you to print the `span` only if you need to. I would also suggest you to check your brackets to avoid PHP errors.